# Como criptografar a senha no cadastro de um novo usuário e como reconhece-lá no login desse usuário?

Tags: php, mysql

esse é o código que processa o cadastro

```
    <?php
    include_once("conexao.php");

    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $celular = $_POST['celular'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $senha = $_POST['senha'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nome,celular,email,senha) VALUES ('$nome','$celular','$email','$senha')";

    $salvar = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);

    $linhas = mysqli_affected_rows($conexao);

    mysqli_close($conexao); ?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html lang="pt-br">

    <head>
        <title>Loja - Cadastro</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0" />
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#FF0000">
        <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
        <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store" />
        <link rel="icon" href="../imagens/favicon.png" type="image/png" />
        <link href="../css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection" />
        <link href="../css/materialize.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection" />
        <link href="../css/animate.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    </head>
<body>
    <?php
        include("navbarforms.php");
    ?>

    <div class="container-fluid">

    <?php
        if($linhas == 1){
        echo "<h4>Cadastro efetuado com sucesso!</h4>";
        header("Location: ../entrar.php");
        } else {
        echo "<h5 class='red-text'>Usuário <strong>$email</strong> já existente no sistema</h5><br><p class='text-blue mdfont'>Redirecionando para a pagina de cadastro...</p>";
        header("refresh: 5; url=../cadastrar.php");
        }
    ?>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

e esse é o codigo que processa o login

```
    <?php
session_start();
include("conexao.php");

if (empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['senha'])) {
    header("Location: ../entrar.php;");
    exit();
}

$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['email']);
$senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['senha']);

$query = "SELECT email, senha FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$email' AND senha = '$senha'";

$result = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);

$row = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($row == 1) {
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    header("location: ../index.php");
    exit();
} else {
    $_SESSION['nao_autenticado'] = true;
    header("location: ../entrar.php");
    exit();
}

?>
```

gostaria de saber como envio a senha criptografada e depois consigo logar com a senha inserida no cadastro.

Answer (score -1):

Pegue o campo e use a criptografia que usou para manda-la pro SELECT
ex no cadastro vc usou md5 em $_POST['senha'];
ficando assim md5($_POST['senha']);
na hora de fazer o login vc faz a mesma coisa, assim, quando vc for checar a senha criptografada, estará enviando a senha igual a do banco de dados caso o usuário estiver digitado corretamente